# How to graph mysql data in python?

Tags: python, mysql, sql

Let's say I get sales data every 15 minutes. The sales transactions are stored in a mysql database. I need to be able to graph this data, and allow the user to re-size the scale of time. The info would be graphed on a django website.

How would I go about doing this, and are there any open source tools that I could look into?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**HighCharts**](http://www.highcharts.com/) is a very nice feature rich charting library written in pure JavaScript.  It is very dynamic and there are a lot of [**demos**](http://highcharts.com/demo/) available showing all the code involved in creating the chart.  You can also view the [**documentation**](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/) for full details on all the features and how to manipulate them.  To get started check out  [**How To Use**](http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/how-to-use).  You can also find a lot of helpful information here on SO.

Comment: Wow this library is incredible!

Answer (score 1):

HighCharts have awesome features you can also build pivot charts using that one but they will charge you .You can look over Py Chart also

Comment: Highcharts is free as long as it is **not** used in a commercial application.  If it is the commercial licensing in my opinion is very reasonable since it is very easy to use and very robust.  Also, since it is javascript it will run on anything.  I bought the [Developers License](http://shop.highsoft.com/highcharts.html) which allows me to use it as often and in as many application as I want.

Answer (score 1):

We used [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) python package and it worked well.